# Double click editor height adjust to expand

Tags: feature-request, editor

I think it would a really useful addition if you double click on the gray bar that allows you to stretch the editor's height that it would automatically expand, or perhaps expand to fit the entire content in the text box. Similar to how Microsoft Office causes any of it's table type cells to auto expand to fit a cells contents when you double click on the edge.

Comment: not really necessary but it may be useful... +1